# creating increment button that shuts off if margin greater then 2800 pxs

Tags: jquery

I'm making a slider, and I'm trying to figure out how I'd program a button specifically.

I'd like it to move left in increments of 700 pxs on click, but once the marginLeft is greater then 2800 pxs for it not do anything on click.

right now I have the part that moves the container in increments, but I'm not sure how to make the part where it does nothing after "slider_container" has a marginLeft of greater then 2800 px.

```
$("#left").click(function () {
    $("#slider_container").animate ({
        marginLeft: "+=700px"
    },450 );
});
```

I was wondering why the following doesn't work:

```
if ($("#slider_container").css("marginLeft") >= 2800) {
      $("#right").click(function () {
    $("#slider_container").animate ({
        marginLeft: "-=0px"
    },450 );
});  
}
else
{
    $("#right").click(function () {
    $("#slider_container").animate ({
        marginLeft: "-=700px"
    },450 );
});  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#left").click(function () {
    var margin = parseInt($("#slider_container").css("marginLeft")),
        move = Math.min(700, 2800 - margin);
    if (move > 0) {
        $("#slider_container").animate ({
            marginLeft: "+=" + move + "px"
        },450 );
    }
});
```

In the code you just added to the question, you need to put the `if` inside the `function` for the click event. Also, `animate to "-=0px"`, does it make any sense?

Comment: hmmm that ended up breaking everything after it in the script

Comment: hmm so that didn't seem to work, but it didn't break anything.  I might have actually said that wrong.  The right button, once slider_container is greater then 2800 pixels shouldn't add anything more onto the margin, and for the left button when slider_container's marginleft is less then 700 is shouldn't take away anymore.

Comment: in the fiddle click any of the thumb nails to get to the slider.

Comment: Just change `Math.min` for `Math.max` and `2800 - margin` for `margin`.. It is not a complex logic

Comment: I added to the question, just wondering why that doesn't work

Comment: can you help me in chat really quick?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20001/discussion-between-loriensleafs-and-diego)

Answer (score 0):

alright, I got it working, here's the solution I came up with:

```
$("#right").click(function () {


if (parseInt($("#slider_container").css("marginLeft")) < -2100) {
    $("#slider_container").animate ({
        marginLeft: -2800
    },450 ); 
}
else
{
    $("#slider_container").animate ({
        marginLeft: "-=700px"
    },450 ); 

}
});

$("#left").click(function () {


if (parseInt($("#slider_container").css("marginLeft")) > -699) {
    $("#slider_container").animate ({
        marginLeft: 0
    },450 ); 
}
else
{
    $("#slider_container").animate ({
        marginLeft: "+=700px"
    },450 ); 

}
});
```