# Increment slider buttons ignores if/else statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [creating increment button that shuts off if margin greater then 2800 pxs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530079/creating-increment-button-that-shuts-off-if-margin-greater-then-2800-pxs)

I have a slider and I'm advancing it by making the `slider_container` `margin-left` negative, so increments of `-700`.  When the `margin-left` is at `-3500px` that's the last slide and I'd like the right button to stop subtracting `700` from the container.  This is how I'm trying to do this but it doesn't seem to work, it just keeps moving past the last slide.

```
$("#right").click(function () {
    if ($("#slider_container").css("marginLeft") < -1000) {
        $("#slider_container").animate({
            marginLeft: 0
        }, 450); 
    }
    else {
        $("#slider_container").animate({
            marginLeft: "-=700px"
        }, 450); 
    }
});
```

I have a [JSFiddle set up here](http://jsfiddle.net/6M73x/10/), click on any of the thumbnails to see the slider

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you are comparing string with number.

```
console.log(typeof($("#slider_container").css("marginLeft")));
```

code above will return you **string** and you are comparing this with number (-1000) so condition will always be false.

Either you can manually convert the string to number:

```
$("#slider_container").css("marginLeft").replace("px", "");
```

or use plugin such as [JSize](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/) which exactly does that.

Comment: so I ended up figuring out an answer, but I don't completely understand what parseInt does, can you explain that to me?

Comment: parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer

Comment: when you just have $("#slider_container").css("marginLeft") doesn't that also just find an integer value?  Why do you have to have the parseInt() there?

Comment: No it doesn't, it returns you a string with px at the end. That is what I explained in answer. parseInt will convert any string to number and it ignores trailing chars eg 'px'. or you can use replace.